# Checkboxs in a from: has_many. Multiple values aren't being read by rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

There seems to be an inconsistency between what is being submitted from the form, and what the rails server is identifying as params... unless I'm doing something wrong / not understanding how parameter arrays work... which is possible.

this is how I'm making my checkboxes:

```
    current_event.competitions.map { |competition|
        content_tag(:div, class: "checkbox"){
            check_box_tag("attendance[competition_ids]", competition.id, @attendance.competitions.include?(competition.id)) + 
            label("attendance[competition_ids]", competition.id, label_with_price(competition))
        }
    }.join.html_safe
```

this is what the chrome web inspector is saying is being sent to the server:

```
attendance[competition_ids]:1
attendance[competition_ids]:2
attendance[competition_ids]:3
```

but Rails is throwing this error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

and this is my params helper method is my  controller

```
params[:attendance].permit(:package, :level, competition_ids: [])
```

params identified by rails:
Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qZ1gtwZoXgs9P0HdberzrsMO7L1NftmB8yGso0WquOY=",
 "attendance"=>{"competition_ids"=>"3"},
 "discounts"=>[""],
 "commit"=>"Register"}
```

shouldn't my params look more like:

```
"attendance"=>{"competition_ids"=>["1","2","3"]}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no inconsistency actually. All of the checkboxes have the same name attribute, so you only see the "last" value. It's basically setting the param value to 1, then 2 and then 3.

If you want an array, the name attribute has to end with `[]`, i.e. `attendance[competition_ids][]`

That'll be interpreted server-side as an array of values.

---

If you think of it as a Ruby hash, it makes sense

```
params["attendance"]["competition_ids"] = 1
params["attendance"]["competition_ids"] = 2
params["attendance"]["competition_ids"] = 3
```

the same key is being overwritten again and again. But if you add the `[]` to the name, the behavior is closer to

```
params["attendance"]["competition_ids"] = []
params["attendance"]["competition_ids"] << 1
params["attendance"]["competition_ids"] << 2
params["attendance"]["competition_ids"] << 3
```

Comment: ah. that does make sense! Silly misunderstanding of HTTP! bah!